# Can I add default dependencies to Azure DevOps pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure Repo with a pipeline that calls a script when triggered. The script needs a few dependencies to perform the work. Is there a way to have the dependencies by default to avoid having to install them every time the script is triggered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid installing dependencies each time pipeline runs, you need to build your own self-hosted agent

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser

> Self-hosted agents give you more control to install dependent software
> needed for your builds and deployments. Also, machine-level caches and
> configuration persist from run to run, which can boost speed.